# ansible: Variable not reinitialized using a role

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

i have a strange behaviour that i don't understand

Playbook "vars_roles.yml":

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    msg_role3: "first_run"

  roles:
    - role: role3

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    msg_role3: "second_run"

  roles:
    - role: role3
```

Content of role3 :

> cat roles/role3/defaults/main.yml

```
---
# defaults file for role3
add_value: false
msg_role3: "default"

tab_msg:
  - "Init value: {{ msg_role3 }}"
```

> cat roles/role3/tasks/main.yml

```
---
# tasks file for role3

- name: Value
  debug:
    msg: "Variable is {{ msg_role3 }}"
- name: Content of Array
  debug:
    var: tab_msg

- name: Add "value" into Array
  set_fact:
    tab_msg: "{{ (tab_msg) + [item] }}"
  loop:
    - "value: {{ msg_role3 }}"
  when: add_value | bool

- name: Content of Array after add value
  debug:
    var: tab_msg
```

So, my problem came from the set_fact with the list 'tab_msg: "{{ (tab_msg) + [item] }}"'
if this task is played, the list "tab_msg" keep values from the first run of the role "role3"

Example without the set_fact :

```
ansible-playbook vars_roles.yml -e add_value=false
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [role3 : Value] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:28:59 +0100 (0:00:00.055)       0:00:00.055 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Variable is first_run"
}

TASK [role3 : Content of Array] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:28:59 +0100 (0:00:00.053)       0:00:00.108 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tab_msg": [
        "Init value: first_run"
    ]
}

TASK [role3 : Add "value" into Array] *********************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:28:59 +0100 (0:00:00.052)       0:00:00.161 *******
skipping: [localhost] => (item=value: first_run)

TASK [role3 : Content of Array after add value] ***********************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:28:59 +0100 (0:00:00.052)       0:00:00.214 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tab_msg": [
        "Init value: first_run"
    ]
}

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [role3 : Value] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:28:59 +0100 (0:00:00.058)       0:00:00.272 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Variable is second_run"
}

TASK [role3 : Content of Array] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:28:59 +0100 (0:00:00.047)       0:00:00.319 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tab_msg": [
        "Init value: second_run"
    ]
}

TASK [role3 : Add "value" into Array] *********************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:28:59 +0100 (0:00:00.048)       0:00:00.368 *******
skipping: [localhost] => (item=value: second_run)

TASK [role3 : Content of Array after add value] ***********************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:28:59 +0100 (0:00:00.052)       0:00:00.420 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tab_msg": [
        "Init value: second_run"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Example with set_fact played :

```
ansible-playbook vars_roles.yml -e add_value=true
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [role3 : Value] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:31:44 +0100 (0:00:00.052)       0:00:00.052 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Variable is first_run"
}

TASK [role3 : Content of Array] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:31:44 +0100 (0:00:00.052)       0:00:00.104 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tab_msg": [
        "Init value: first_run"
    ]
}

TASK [role3 : Add "value" into Array] *********************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:31:44 +0100 (0:00:00.049)       0:00:00.154 *******
ok: [localhost] => (item=value: first_run)

TASK [role3 : Content of Array after add value] ***********************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:31:44 +0100 (0:00:00.054)       0:00:00.208 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tab_msg": [
        "Init value: first_run",
        "value: first_run"
    ]
}

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [role3 : Value] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:31:44 +0100 (0:00:00.053)       0:00:00.262 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Variable is second_run"
}

TASK [role3 : Content of Array] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:31:44 +0100 (0:00:00.047)       0:00:00.309 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tab_msg": [
        "Init value: first_run",
        "value: first_run"
    ]
}

TASK [role3 : Add "value" into Array] *********************************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:31:44 +0100 (0:00:00.047)       0:00:00.357 *******
ok: [localhost] => (item=value: second_run)

TASK [role3 : Content of Array after add value] ***********************************************************************************************************************
Tuesday 27 October 2020  16:31:44 +0100 (0:00:00.055)       0:00:00.412 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tab_msg": [
        "Init value: first_run",
        "value: first_run",
        "value: second_run"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=8    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result, you see, is correct. See [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). Value assigned in [*set_fact*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html#ansible-builtin-set-fact-set-host-facts-from-a-task) has higher precedence (19.) than role's defaults (2.). In addition to this, the value assigned in *set_fact* [will be available to subsequent plays during an ansible-playbook run](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html#synopsis).

In the simplified example below, *set_fact* (19.) has higher precedence than *play vars* (12.)

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    msg_role3: "first_run"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: msg_role3
    - set_fact:
        msg_role3: "Added value"
      when: add_value|default(false)|bool

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    msg_role3: "second_run"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: msg_role3
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****

  msg_role3: first_run

PLAY [localhost] ****

  msg_role3: second_run
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "add_value=true"

PLAY [localhost] ****

  msg_role3: first_run


PLAY [localhost] ****

  msg_role3: Added value
```

---

The solution to your problem is removing *tab_msg* from *defaults/main.yml* and putting it into the *tasks/main.yml*. For example

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role3/defaults/main.yml
add_value: false
msg_role3: "default"
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role3/tasks/main.yml
- name: Init tab_msg
  set_fact:
    tab_msg:
      - "Init value: {{ msg_role3 }}"
- name: Value
  ...
```

Comment: Okay, i see. My problem is that the variable "tab_msg" is know in the main playbook, I need to have something like private variable into the role.

Comment: Optionally, initialize the variable in the task. I've added an example to the answer.